# Placing Wave Texture In Center Of Geometry

Tags: texturing, node-editor, procedural

I am a Node Noob and i was wondering how/if i could center this wave texture in the middle of my knob here. I did a knife project on the "pointer" so the UV of the top of the knob where i want it centered is not good. [image]

Thanks!

Can provide a blend file, but i do not remember how to do that.

This is what im going for:
[image]

Comment: Not sure I'm wrapping my head around what you want.  Can you provide a mockup of what you want?

Comment: Try using the mapping node, it should let you move it with the location values.

Comment: I Have updated to show what i mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the texture coordinates (0,0) to start at the center of your object, use *Object* Texture Coordinates:

[image: Coord]

Comment: This worked, thank you!